# Virtual environment created with tox failed to use pip install

Tags: python, tox

Thanks in advance, if any help.

#### background

- os: osx 10.15.3 (19D76)
- python: /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
- tox: 3.14.5 imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/**init**.pyc

#### problem description

i was going to play with openstack/horizon in pike branch like below:

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack/horizon.git
cd horizon
git checkout -b pike remotes/origin/stable/pike
tox -e runserver
```

and it failed with message:

```
runserver create: /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver
runserver installdeps: -r/Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/requirements.txt, -r/Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/test-requirements.txt
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code -6), logfile: /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/log/runserver-2.log
=========================================================== log start ============================================================

============================================================ log end =============================================================
____________________________________________________________ summary _____________________________________________________________
ERROR:   runserver: InvocationError for command /Users
```

#### things i've done

so i add -vvv to the tom command like below:

```
tox -e runserver -vvv
```

it showed message below:

```
using tox.ini: /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/tox.ini (pid 53225)
  removing /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/log
using tox-3.14.5 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc (pid 53225)
skipping sdist step
runserver start: getenv /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver
runserver uses /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
runserver reusing: /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver
runserver finish: getenv /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver after 0.12 seconds
runserver start: finishvenv
runserver finish: finishvenv  after 0.00 seconds
runserver start: envreport
setting PATH=/Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/qemu/4.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
[53228] /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon$ /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin/python -m pip freeze >.tox/runserver/log/runserver-3.log
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code -6), logfile: /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/log/runserver-3.log
=========================================================== log start ============================================================

============================================================ log end =============================================================
____________________________________________________________ summary _____________________________________________________________
ERROR:   runserver: InvocationError for command /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin/python -m pip freeze (exited with code -6 (SIGABRT)) (exited with code -6)
```

i've tried to trace into the error as follows, but i have no idea how can these stuff help me. 
add pdb to /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin/pip

```
#!/Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    sys.exit(main())
```

then i activate the virtualenv and step into the pdb:

```
 pip freeze
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/bin/pip(11)<module>()
-> sys.exit(main())
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(22)main()
-> def main(args=None):
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(23)main()
-> if args is None:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(24)main()
-> args = sys.argv[1:]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(27)main()
-> deprecation.install_warning_logger()
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(29)main()
-> autocomplete()
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(31)main()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(32)main()
-> cmd_name, cmd_args = parse_command(args)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(59)parse_command()
-> def parse_command(args):
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(61)parse_command()
-> parser = create_main_parser()
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(70)parse_command()
-> general_options, args_else = parser.parse_args(args)
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(73)parse_command()
-> if general_options.version:
(Pdb) l
 68         #  general_options: ['--timeout==5']
 69         #  args_else: ['install', '--user', 'INITools']
 70         general_options, args_else = parser.parse_args(args)
 71
 72         # --version
 73  ->     if general_options.version:
 74             sys.stdout.write(parser.version)  # type: ignore
 75             sys.stdout.write(os.linesep)
 76             sys.exit()
 77
 78         # pip || pip help -> print_help()
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(79)parse_command()
-> if not args_else or (args_else[0] == 'help' and len(args_else) == 1):
(Pdb) l
 74             sys.stdout.write(parser.version)  # type: ignore
 75             sys.stdout.write(os.linesep)
 76             sys.exit()
 77
 78         # pip || pip help -> print_help()
 79  ->     if not args_else or (args_else[0] == 'help' and len(args_else) == 1):
 80             parser.print_help()
 81             sys.exit()
 82
 83         # the subcommand name
 84         cmd_name = args_else[0]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(84)parse_command()
-> cmd_name = args_else[0]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(86)parse_command()
-> if cmd_name not in commands_dict:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(96)parse_command()
-> cmd_args = args[:]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(97)parse_command()
-> cmd_args.remove(cmd_name)
(Pdb) l
 92
 93             raise CommandError(' - '.join(msg))
 94
 95         # all the args without the subcommand
 96         cmd_args = args[:]
 97  ->     cmd_args.remove(cmd_name)
 98
 99         return cmd_name, cmd_args
[EOF]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(99)parse_command()
-> return cmd_name, cmd_args
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py(99)parse_command()->('freeze', [])
-> return cmd_name, cmd_args
(Pdb) l
 94
 95         # all the args without the subcommand
 96         cmd_args = args[:]
 97         cmd_args.remove(cmd_name)
 98
 99  ->     return cmd_name, cmd_args
[EOF]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(40)main()
-> try:
(Pdb) l
 35             sys.stderr.write(os.linesep)
 36             sys.exit(1)
 37
 38         # Needed for locale.getpreferredencoding(False) to work
 39         # in pip._internal.utils.encoding.auto_decode
 40  ->     try:
 41             locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
 42         except locale.Error as e:
 43             # setlocale can apparently crash if locale are uninitialized
 44             logger.debug("Ignoring error %s when setting locale", e)
 45         command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(41)main()
-> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/main.py(45)main()
-> command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py(90)create_command()
-> def create_command(name, **kwargs):
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py(95)create_command()
-> module_path, class_name, summary = commands_dict[name]
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py(96)create_command()
-> module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py(20)import_module()
-> def import_module(name, package=None):
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py(28)import_module()
-> if name.startswith('.'):
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py(37)import_module()
-> __import__(name)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py(184)find_module()
-> def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py(185)find_module()
-> if fullname in self.known_modules:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py(187)find_module()
-> return None
(Pdb) self.known_modules
{'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_filedialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af622d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.SimpleHTTPServer': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af620d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_simpledialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62350>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_parse': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_parse' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_constants': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62410>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.http_client': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58e90>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.xmlrpc_server': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62750>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.configparser': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58c90>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.parse': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_parse' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_response': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.response' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_dialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62290>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_error': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.error' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_request': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.request' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.http_cookies': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58dd0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_dnd': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62450>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_font': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62550>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.response': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.response' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_commondialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af624d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.socketserver': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af621d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.copyreg': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58cd0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_ttk': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af623d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves._thread': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62210>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_messagebox': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62590>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_tksimpledialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af625d0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.email_mime_multipart': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58f50>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.queue': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62150>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves._dummy_thread': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58d50>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.html_entities': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58e10>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_scrolledtext': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62310>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_tkfiledialog': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62510>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.builtins': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58c50>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib_robotparser': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.robotparser' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_colorchooser': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62490>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.xmlrpc_client': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62710>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.email_mime_base': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58ed0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.cPickle': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62110>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.BaseHTTPServer': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62050>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.email_mime_text': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58fd0>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.reprlib': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62190>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.http_cookiejar': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58d90>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.error': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.error' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.email_mime_image': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58f10>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.html_parser': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58e50>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.dbm_gnu': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58d10>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.email_mime_nonmultipart': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af58f90>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62250>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.robotparser': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.robotparser' (built-in)>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.tkinter_tix': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62390>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.CGIHTTPServer': <pip._vendor.six.MovedModule object at 0x10af62090>, 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.request': <module 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib.request' (built-in)>}
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py(187)find_module()->None
-> return None
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py(180)find_module()
-> def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py(181)find_module()
-> if fullname in self.known_modules:
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py(183)find_module()
-> return None
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/six.py(183)find_module()->None
-> return None
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(4)<module>()
-> from __future__ import absolute_import
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(4)<module>()
-> from __future__ import absolute_import
(Pdb) l
  1     # The following comment should be removed at some point in the future.
  2     # mypy: disallow-untyped-defs=False
  3
  4  -> from __future__ import absolute_import
  5
  6     import sys
  7
  8     from pip._internal.cache import WheelCache
  9     from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
 10     from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
 11     from pip._internal.models.format_control import FormatControl
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(6)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(8)<module>()
-> from pip._internal.cache import WheelCache
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(9)<module>()
-> from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(10)<module>()
-> from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(11)<module>()
-> from pip._internal.models.format_control import FormatControl
(Pdb) n
> /Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/freeze.py(12)<module>()
-> from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze
(Pdb) n
zsh: abort      pip freeze
```

i think it might be caused by

```
/Users/xiaojueguan/code/OpenStack/horizon/.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/six.py(187)find_module()->None
```

which failed to excute

```
from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze
```

i do have no ideas what further infoes that i can provide to improve this question.

#### 2020/03/03

today i tried further with pdb, which can be quite clumsy when debugging with pdb.

environment change:
 -today i've changed my virtualenv version from 16.7.6 to 20.0.7

conclusion:

> pip failed to import it's module as a cause of below:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py(367)__init__()
-> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

i've tried to `s` into `_dlopen function, but it made the terminal to abort again. i've found it was imported from a module`_ctypes`. With so much clumsy trying, i got an idea: module`_ctypes` might not be defined.
and it was true.

```
(Pdb) c
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py(367)__init__()
-> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
(Pdb) type(_dlopen)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
(Pdb) _os.name
'posix'
(Pdb) _os.name == "posix"
True
(Pdb) _ctypes
*** NameError: name '_ctypes' is not defined
(Pdb) _ctypes
*** NameError: name '_ctypes' is not defined
```

progress
i'v used pdb to dive into the next step with problem by type `n` and `s` to step into the problem.
i'v add pdb to these erea as below:

```
./.tox/runserver/bin/pip:8:    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/roboto/awsqueryrequest.py:35:    import pdb as debugger
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py:9:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py:12:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py:16:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scss/compiler.py:495:            import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymeta/runtime.py:213:            import pdb; pdb. set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/tools/nontrivial.py:78:    import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py:202:        #import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/debug.py:7:import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/ext/dtcompat.py:2230:    import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybars/_compiler.py:665:        self._result.grow(u"    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()\n")
Binary file ./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybars/_compiler.pyc matches
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py:15:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py:12:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py:21:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py:96:    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py:24:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/locators.py:1250:                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/metadata.py:707:        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py:111:            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py:419:    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py:437:        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py:1336:            #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py:1344:                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:97:        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py:46:import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py:1501:                import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asn1crypto/_int.py:56: import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asn1crypto/_elliptic_curve.py:50:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asn1crypto/keys.py:21:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asn1crypto/_perf/_big_num_ctypes.py:34:    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pankoclient/v2/alarm.py:60:        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py:69:        import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/pyparsing.py:1240:                import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py:1240:                import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py:7:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12:import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/evalexception/evalcontext.py:6:import pdb
./.tox/runserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py:1217:                import pdb
./doc/source/contributor/topics/testing.rst:213:   ``import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`` anywhere in your codebase will drop the
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: that's hard, cause i tried to reproduce the case in the virtual machine i can access, but it failed

Comment: the code from `pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand` which failed actually lived there. but python seems failed to find it and import. i am curious how it import  and why it fails.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What is the command that was executed and what was the resulting error message if any? Is it possible to shorten up the `tox.ini` to a smaller version that still reproduces the issue? All of this would be really helpful pieces of information.

Comment: i've tried to reproduce on centos server with what i've on my mac, all things workout ok.

Comment: No idea... Have you tried using a different Python? Try eventually a different maintenance version (assuming you want to stay on _2.7_), or one distributed by someone else (for example install from the [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) instead of from _homebrew_).

Comment: i am curious with reason more than the result

Comment: any good tools to help to analyze the code and figure out why?

Comment: "_i am curious with reason more than the result_", I see. Probably rephrase (or recreate) the whole question and its content with the right keywords to attract people with the right skills.

Comment: Did you raise this issue also in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc+label%3A%22type%3Aquestion+%3Agrey_question%3A%22+) and / or checked if there's anyone there with the same problem?

Comment: I've checked the issue, it was not me who raised the issue. The experience of the issue's owner is much like me. So this was not the one time problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/install/system-requirements.html), Horizon needs Python 3.6 or 3.7. So I don't think you can run it with Python2.7.

Even [Horizon's tox file](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/tox.ini) only mentions Python3.

Comment: horizon in pike version is ok with python2.7, and i also failed in pike, what's more my colleague's pc is ok with the staff.